# Can Pulse Oximeter Service (0x1822) be shown on "nRF Connect for Mobile"

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using arduino to send message through BLE to a mobile, which uses "nRF Connect for Mobile" to scan the arduino.

I am able to get the information of Blood pressure (0x1810) and Health Thermometer (0x1809), but fail for Pulse Oximeter Service (0x1822)

It only displays

```
Value: (0x) 00-63-00-50-00
```

What I expect is

```
00 = flags

63-00 = SLOAT of the SpO2 value, i.e. 99%

50-00 = SLOAT of the pulse rate, i.e. 80
```

As it doesn't have symptom like "invalid data syntax", I wonder if this service is defined by this app.

```
// For Blood Pressure service (0x1810): Blood Pressure Measurement (0x2A35)
byte flags1 = 0b00000000;
byte SYS = 100;
byte DIA = 160;
byte MAP = 120;
byte BP[8] = {flags1, SYS, 0, DIA, 0, MAP, 0};

pChara1_1->setValue(BP, 8);
pChara1_1->indicate();
// The mobile app (nRF Connect) display the systolic pressure: 100 mmHg successfully (also the diastolic and mean pressure)

// For Pulse Oximeter Service (0x1822): PLX Spot-check Measurement (0x2A5E)
byte flags3 = 0b00000000;
byte Sp = 99;
byte PR = 80;
byte SPO2[5] = {flags3, Sp, 0, PR, 0};

pChara3_1->setValue(SPO2, 5);
pChara3_1->indicate();

// For Pulse Oximeter Service (0x1822): PLX Features (0x2A60)
byte flags4[2] = {0b00000000,0b00000000};

pChara3_3->setValue(flags4, 2);

// It turns out "Value: (0x) 00-63-00-50-00"
```

Expected results

```
SpO2: 99%
Pulse rate: 80
```

Actual results

```
Value: (0x) 00-63-00-50-00
```

Comment: I believe the parsing of characteristic data for PulseOximetry is not supported in the NRF connect app. I a working on the exact same issue.

Comment: I highly suggest you to look at Windows C++/C# BLE GUI sample app with which you can pair and connect to your nRF server device and discover the GATT profiles, services and characteristics. You can subscribe to characteristic for notification if it is notifiable, or read it if it is readable or write it if it is writable https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/

Answer (score 0):

In the official Bluetooth Generic Attributes Profile Specifications found here:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/

And the link  to the pdf on that page:
https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=304965

the return value from Pulse Oximeter Service PLX returns a SFLOAT.
SFLOAT is a 16-bit word beginning with a signed 4-bit integer exponent followed by a signed 12-bit Mantissa, each in twos-complement form.
For example :
Your OxiValue : 0x0063.
Exponent: 0x0 is 0.
Mantissa: 0x063 is 99.
Result: 99 * 10^0 is 99.
As the exponent is 0 , this example is easy as 10^0 is 1.
A  signed 4-bit integer in twos-complement form is represented by the decimal range - 8   to +7,
where -8 is BIN 1000, 0 is BIN 0000 and +7 is BIN 0111.
0xB is BIN 1011 gives DEC -4.
0x4 is BIN 0100 gives DEC 4.
0x3 is BIN 0011 gives DEC 3.
This means hex-numbers larger than 0x7 will be negative up to 0xF which is -1 Dec.

The easy way to convert from SFLOAT to DEC is to make a lookup table for all the 16 values of the exponent part.
For the mantissa part, if it is a positive number, just convert the hex value to integer. for negative numbers its more complicated. You will have to Google that.

Now to the nRF Connect for Mobile.
To represent these numbers you have to convert them to integer and use the presentation format Int. This is only possible from nRF Connect  version 4.19.0. and higher, otherwise You have to send the int value as text.

Comment: My answer is a bit ill formatted so it seems overcomplicated.
The reason is that the text editor kept complaining to use code formatting. I had to edit some formulas to look like plain text to post it. 
Sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also got the same complains for many times when I posted this question. But sorry for that I dun really get what you mean...

Comment: I dun understand the reason for existence of signed and unsigned bit in SFLOAT. I just know that <nRF Connect for Mobile> can show another service which specification is similar to the PLX service. So I am pretty sure my code is right.

Comment: You mentioned that I need to convert from SFLOAT to DEC. As you can see from my code, I defined <byte SYS = 100> and <byte Sp = 99>, which both are DEC. However, <nRF Connect> can only display SYS...It displays PLX in SFLOAT (which I classify as FAIL)

Comment: The nRF Connect for Mobile is just a tool. Nordic Semiconductor claims it can handle most of the characteristic formats and SFLOAT is not one of the supported.  
If a format is not supported You get the raw data.  
To explain the SFOAT a bit more: For example, value 0x0E0113 :

  exponent: 0x0E = -2
  mantissa: 0x0113 = 275 

  -> Actual value: 275 * 10^-2 = 2.75

Comment: I see your point. However, as I mentioned, I was able to get the expected results for blood pressure service, which also uses SFLOAT as format as indicated here https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.blood_pressure_measurement.xml

Comment: Yes you are right, but its not supported from the RAW-data. The  characteristic profile  is used to select the format.
Most services and characteristics are supported, but this one isn't.

Comment: Do you mean Blood Pressure and other services support RAW-data but PLX service doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed the case that parsing for this characteristic and few others is not supported in the nRF app itself. You're doing nothing wrong.

I have created an issue on the nRF repository and the maintainer has said that he will try to implement the one characteristic parsing that I mentioned.

Link to [Issue](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-nRF-Connect/issues/134).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps late to the party, but we're adding PLX characteristics parsers to nRF Connect 4.25.4.